# How to set 3 arguments to ChromeDriver selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, arguments

`var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options)`

I want to create a ChromeDriver in C# selenium with 3 arguments but it only takes (string directory, ChromeOptions options) and (ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options)

How can I create a ChromeDriver with chrome driver directory, options, and service?

Comment: What 3 arguments do you want to pass it? Please clarify your question. You can illustrate what those three arguments are by writing some pseudo code. Something like "I want to pass these arguments: `new ChromeDriver(a, b, c)`." Be sure to give a, b and c descriptive names so we know what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is to launch a new ChromeDriver and to pass:

- driver directory
- service
- options

In this case, *driver directory* should be passed with the service object instantiation.

```
string driverDirectory = "...path to the directory containing ChromeDriver.exe";
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverDirectory);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

---

**Selenium 4 C# related api docs**

Find more details here:

- https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver.htm
- https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService.htm